# Splash screen is still using background image How to release vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, dispose

I am copying all the images from the server to the local workstation so that one cannot tamper with them and when the application closes I want to delete those files.

currently I just tested with the splash screens background image. I copied the file to temp folder in workstation and it worked well.

But when I tried to delete it I am not able to do so as it is still used by splash screen.

How to release it from splash screen?

I tried to delete the directory

I am using the image on splash screen load method with the following code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("\\bwingssrv01\NRSRoot$\NRS_img", "c:\windows\temp\NRS_img", True)
Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("c:\windows\temp\NRS_img\splash.jpg")
```

I have tried to delete the directory on MyApplication_Shutdown

Comment: The given variable where the image is stored should have a `Dispose()` extension method. Alternative you might rely on the `using` statement which will take care of all the disposing-related actions automatically. In any case (and for the future), please provide some code or explain clearly what you are doing (e.g., what controls/classes are you using?) because your question is too abstract to be on-topic here.

Comment: Why don't you think about this for a little bit and ask yourself if you *really* want to delete your splashscreen image?  Keep the files you copy separate from the files your program needs to do its job.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by using delegate in SplashScreen:

I just tried to dispose the background image in the function called from My MDI form at the end of my code and was successful.

I used following code to solve the issue:

A delegate in my SplashScreen as:

```
Public Delegate Sub unload()
```

and following function in my SplashScreen as:

```
Public Sub unload1()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New unload(AddressOf unload1))
    Else
        Me.Visible = False 'to avoid showing the error image in background
        Me.BackgroundImage.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

At the end of my MDI form I used following:

```
SplashScreen1.unload1()
Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
```